# Favorite Tag Buttons partly sticking off page

Tags: bug, tags, design, tag-watching

I appear to have found a bug, when adding Favorite tags, I find that the buttons are half off the page (this is of the [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) site):

[image: Favorite Buttons Off]

Although on other sites it looks more like this:

[image: Favorite Buttons Less Off than AskUbuntu Site]

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with Firefox `41.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.15.04.2`.

Comment: Looks like it's specific to one site, do you see it happening on other sites as well?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Well, if I look at the buttons on other sites they are slightly off, but the word "Add" is still visible unlike on the AskUbuntu site.

Comment: It seems to be on all sites (Firefox 39 / Windows 7)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda please mention your OS and browser. I can confirm this on Chromium 45.0.2454.85 and Firefox 41.0 both running on Debian. It might also be worth mentioning that the bug is not present on sites with the old CSS style ([scifi.se], for example).

Comment: @terdon: Ok, I have updated my question to include the information which you requested.